# How to determine that bash script is run on the 'console' not in remote terminal session?

Tags: bash, console

How to determine that bash script is run on the 'console' not in remote terminal session?  I would think that there is some way to determine the script is running on /dev/console?  Or am I barking up the wrong (binary) tree?

Comment: Bash has a test condition `[[ -t 0 ]]` ` -t fd True if file descriptor fd is open and refers to a terminal.`

Comment: @Paul_Pedant it's still true over an interactive ssh session (for example)

Answer (score 5):

This sounds like a possible [XY problem.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

An old Unix command `tty` can tell you which device your terminal is on.
So something like this might do what you're asking:

```
if [ $(tty) = "/dev/console" ]; then
    echo "Yes, I am on the console."
else
    echo "No, I am not on the console."
fi
```

**However,** a program running on a login session in a Linux virtual console might instead see `/dev/tty1` or similar. If a serial console is used, you might see `/dev/ttyS0` or other serial port device. The only times you might see a literal `/dev/console` might be when running in emergency shell/single-user mode. Knowing which device(s) might be valid consoles is not trivial; that is part of the reason why `/etc/securetty` exists and is configurable by the system administrator.

(If you chose to reject the serial ports, a system administrator somewhere trying to use a serial-over-LAN connection to fix a *very* remote system might hate you.)

If a process or script is run as a `systemd` service it might not have a TTY at all in a traditional sense; instead  its standard output and standard error will be plugged into `systemd`'s journaling facility, which may or may not pass it onto the console at boot time depending on how the service is configured.

Please, edit your question to specify *why* you want to know whether you're on 'console' or not, so we can try and find a way to get the answer to your question in a sense that is appropriate to your actual need.

Answer (score 0):

If you run `ps axu`, look in the TTY column for the root "console" that the process uses.

Every process has a parent working up to the root init process

Answer (score -1):

Explore, with `diff`, the results of `env | sort` in the two environments. `$DISPLAY` is one to check.

Also, read `man isatty`.